# max_by returning wrong value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have hash which looks like this

```
@hash =  { 1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[], 4=>[],5=>[], 6=>[], 7=>[
[{"value"=>1.58, "title"=>"sun", "quantity" => 2}],
[{"value"=>1.99, "title"=>"sophia", "quantity" => 5}],
[{"value"=>6.30, "title"=>"roam", "quantity" => 15}],
[{"value"=>3.981, "title"=>"jia", "quantity" => "4"}]], 8 => [], 9 => [], 10 => [] }
```

and I am trying to find max value based on value tag for each particular index value such as

out put should look like this

```
    @hash =  { 1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=> nil, 4=>nil,5=>nil, 6=>nil, 7=>[
[{"value"=>6.30, "title"=>"roam", "quantity" => 15}], 8 => nil, 9 => nil, 10 => nil }
```

I hope expected output is clear

So I am trying to get max from following code

```
  for t in 0..10
     if !@hash[t].nil?                                                                     
        @hash[t]  = @hash[t].max_by{|i| i[0]['value'].to_i} 
        puts "----------"
        puts @hash.to_s
     end
  end
```

but I only get first value form hash and null for other index instead of giving max value for that particular index. The puts in this loop gives me this
which is wrong

```
[{"title":"sun","value":1.58, "quantity => 2"}], null, null, null, null..
```

dont know what is wrong

Comment: do you want to keep track of the array id? or just the hash value ?

Comment: just the hash value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
@hash =  { 1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[], 4=>[],5=>[], 6=>[], 7=>[
[{"value"=>1.58, "title"=>"sun", "quantity" => 2}],
[{"value"=>1.99, "title"=>"sophia", "quantity" => 5}],
[{"value"=>6.30, "title"=>"roam", "quantity" => 15}],
[{"value"=>3.981, "title"=>"jia", "quantity" => "4"}]], 8 => [], 9 => [], 10 => [] }

@hash.each do |k, v|
  if v.empty?
    @hash[k] = nil
  else
    @hash[k] = [v.flatten.sort{ |v1, v2| v2['value'] <=> v1['value'] }.first]
  end
end

puts @hash.inspect
#=> {1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=>nil, 4=>nil, 5=>nil, 6=>nil, 7=>[{"value"=>6.3, "title"=>"roam", "quantity"=>15}], 8=>nil, 9=>nil, 10=>nil}
```

Comment: aha, now It worked for this but one question If I need to find again max value among all index then is it correct like this....max_value = @hash.values.select{ |v| v }.map{ |v| v.first['value'] }.max

Comment: Yup, my initial iteration was to find max value and then do a select on hash values.

Comment: You can do: `@hash.values.flatten.map{ |v1| v1['value'] }.max`

Answer (score 2):

```
 @hash =  { 1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[], 4=>[],5=>[], 6=>[], 7=>[
 [{"value"=>1.58, "title"=>"sun", "quantity" => 2}],
 [{"value"=>1.99, "title"=>"sophia", "quantity" => 5}],
 [{"value"=>6.30, "title"=>"roam", "quantity" => 15}],
 [{"value"=>3.981, "title"=>"jia", "quantity" => "4"}]], 8 => [], 9 => [], 10 => [] }

 @hash.each do |key, values|
   if values.empty?
     @hash[key] = nil
   else
     @hash[key] = [values.flatten.max_by{|h| h["value"]}]
   end
 end

 p @hash
```

Comment: Why would you want to destroy the `@hash` object to perform a task like this?

Comment: I guess the requirements is like that the original hash will never be used

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
@hash.map do |key, things|
  [
    key,
    things.max_by { |thing| thing.first["value"].to_i }
  ]
end.to_h
```

Pardon the unhelpful variable names, I'm not quite sure what your data structure represents so I'm not able to pick better names.

Note that this does not edit `@hash`, but returns a new hash.

Comment: This is neat buddy. Please note that `.to_h` will work only for Ruby 2.1.x or above. Nice answer though.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought `Array#to_h` was in activesupport as well. Another option is to wrap the entire thing in `Hash[…]`, or to convert the return value of the `map` into a Hash like thus: `hash_array = @hash.map …; @hash = Hash[hash_array]`.

Comment: or you can `map.with_object({})` which i think looks cleaner than wrapping with `Hash`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `#max_by` as requested (**Not sure why you, as well as many other answers, want to destroy the original hash. All the methods below are non-destructive and will return the requested results.**)

```
 @hash.map.with_object({}) do |(k,v),obj|
   obj[k] = v.empty? ? nil : [v.flatten.max_by{ |h| h["value"]}]
 end
 #=>{1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=>nil, 4=>nil, 5=>nil, 6=>nil, 7=>[{"value"=>6.3, "title"=>"roam", "quantity"=>15}], 8=>nil, 9=>nil, 10=>nil}
```

It could be cleaner if you didn't want the 7th element to be an array of 1 which does not make much sense to me anyway e.g.

```
@hash.map.with_object({}) do |(k,v),obj|
   obj[k] = v.flatten.max_by{ |h| h["value"]}
end
#=> {1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=>nil, 4=>nil, 5=>nil, 6=>nil, 7=>{"value"=>6.3, "title"=>"roam", "quantity"=>15}, 8=>nil, 9=>nil, 10=>nil}
```

Why do you need an array of a single element when all this will do is add complexity? Unless you are appending to this element later?

Or another way

```
@hash.map.with_object({}) do |(k,v),obj|
  obj[k] = v.max_by{|a| a.is_a?(Array) ? a[0]['value'] : a.to_f}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that will give the required output:

```
output_hash = {}

@hash.keys.each do |k|
  output_hash[k] = @hash[k].flatten.max{ |a, b| a["value"] <=> b["value"]  }
end

puts output_hash
```

Answer (score 0):

It could easily be done by a one liner, you can replace `sort_by` with `max_by` if you just want one value

Sort the values descending

```
@hash.values.reject(&:empty?).flatten.sort_by{|x| x['value']}
```

Maximum value hash

```
@hash.values.reject(&:empty?).flatten.max_by{|x| x['value']}
```